# Why does git checkout unchanged but touched files?

Tags: git, touch

In a gitrepo if you touch a file, why is it checked out afterwards?

```
$ ls -l --time-style=full-iso README.md 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 4900 2020-01-16 16:25:41.144000000 +0100 README.md
$ touch README.md 
$ ls -l --time-style=full-iso README.md 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 4900 2020-01-16 16:26:06.316000000 +0100 README.md
$ git checkout .
$ ls -l --time-style=full-iso README.md 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 4899 2020-01-16 16:26:11.960000000 +0100 README.md
```

`git status` does not show the file!

This causes some issues with incremental builds on pull requests right now.
The files are binary identical:

```
$ touch README.md
$ cp README.md README.md_touch
$ git checkout .
$ xxd README.md > README.md.hex
$ xxd README.md_touch > README.md_touch.hex
$ diff README.md.hex README.md_touch.hex
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807971/why-does-git-diff-index-head-result-change-for-touched-files-after-git-diff-or-g) might be related but `git diff-index HEAD` shows nothing for me:

```
$ git diff-index HEAD
$ touch README.md
$ git diff-index HEAD
$ git checkout .
$ git diff-index HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `git checkout .` (which in Git 2.23+ is perhaps better phrased as `git restore .`).  So you specifically *told* Git: *please overwrite all my tracked work-tree files in this part of my work-tree.*  It doesn't matter that the overwrite is with the same contents: you told Git to overwrite, so it did.

(It would not be unreasonable for Git to not touch unchanged files, and there are checkout modes where this does happen and Git doesn't really promise to overwrite unchanged files.  So it could do what you wanted.  But currently, it does this instead.  So don't use `git checkout .`.)

(Remember, the *index* aka *staging area* is never<sup>1</sup> empty.  When you haven't changed a file from the version that was in the commit you checked out, the index contains a copy<sup>2</sup> of the file!  `git checkout .` means *check out all the files that are in the index, overwriting the copies in the work-tree with the copies from the index.*)

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, hardly ever.  You can have an empty index, if you have no tracked files.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the index holds references to Git blob objects, rather than actual copies.  The effect here is the same though.

Comment: In reality I use `git checkout somebranch`, where `README.md` is unchanged. However, i guess that does not change your answer :) thx.

Comment: Actually, `git checkout <branchname>` is pretty different! That's *supposed* to leave modified files in place if possible, and not do a checkout at all if not possible. (It doesn't promise not to touch the timestamps in the process of doing all this, but it's a more reasonable request for *this* form of `git checkout`.)

Comment: The fact that `git checkout` has both destructive (`git checkout -- <paths>`) and nondestructive (`git checkout <branch>`) modes is why Git 2.23 and later have separate commands, `git switch` and `git restore`, that divide the behavior into nondestructive (switch) and destructive (restore) modes.